# Decoding an incorrect UTF-8 string

Tags: character-encoding

I have a little issue with incorrectly encoded data that has made it's way into the Database.  From my research fact finding, I have reached the idea that the string data was copied directly off a page that contains non-utf8 characters, I'm thinking ISO-5589-1.

I have found ways of stopping this from happening in the first place and measures will be put in place to stop this in future, but now to mitigate the damage, I need to know if this mistaken case of encoding can be reversed so that I can get my hands on the intended data?

In my search I've found prevention, but no solution to already mistakenly encoded data.

Here is a snippet of the data :

```
ÃÆÃÆÃâÃ
```

It doesn't seem apparent just looking at it, but copying it  and pasting it into a plaintext editor will show the non-displayed characters as well.

I'm very new to character sets as a whole and generally don;t know if you'll need more information?  I can say that this was captured on LAMP stack if that helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of database? How do you encode / decode ?

Comment: It's a PostgreSQL DB, and I don't think there is any encoding or decoding explicitly being used.

Comment: Please show your codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what exactly happened. As a very quick primer on [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), this simply happens when *bytes*, representing text in a certain encoding, were interpreted using an inappropriate encoding. For example, these are the bytes representing the text "Føö" encoded in UTF-8:

```
46 C3 B8 C3 B6
```

`46` stands for "F", and `C3 B8` and `C3 B6` for "ø" and "ö" respectively.
Interpreting these bytes not according to UTF-8 rules but according to Latin-1 rules would give these characters instead:

> FÃ¸Ã¶

Five characters, one for each byte from the Latin-1 table.

In this case the misinterpretation is "lossless", i.e. each byte of the UTF-8 text made sense in Latin-1. The other way around is not guaranteed. Take "Føö" encoded in Latin-1:

```
46 F8 F6
```

Just three bytes, one for each letter from the Latin-1 table. However, interpreting this in UTF-8 is not possible, the byte sequence `F8 F6` as such is invalid in UTF-8. It's up to the interpreter how to handle this case; it can do anything from throwing an exception (which it arguably should) to replacing the characters with question marks or other placeholders. In this case the transformation is "lossy"; since it's an invalid operation, the result cannot preserve the exact input.

To undo such a mishap you first need to figure out whether the problem was "lossy" or not. If it was, tough luck. If it was "lossless", you may be able to reverse the transformation simply by interpreting and/or saving your data in another encoding, in the right order.

If UTF-8 data was interpreted as Latin-1 data but then (mis-)converted "from Latin-1" to UTF-8, it's possible to reverse this by converting the result from UTF-8 to Latin-1 and interpreting the result as UTF-8.

Figure out what happened in your case and play around.

Read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).